# Spark : how to remove lines in dataset having different values

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset `ds` like this:

```
ds.show():

id1 | id2 | id3 | value  |
1   | 1   | 2   | tom    |
1   | 1   | 2   | tim    |
1   | 1   | 2   | tom    |
2   | 1   | 2   | mary   |
```

I want to remove all lines having different values per keys `(id1,id2,id3)`, the expected output is:

```
id1 | id2 | id3 | value  |
1   | 1   | 2   | tom    |
2   | 1   | 2   | mary   |
```

here I should remove line 1 and line 2 because we have 2 values for the key group

I try to achieve this using:

```
ds.groupBy(id1,id2,id3).distinct()
```

But it's not working

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "_here I should remove line 1 and line 2 because we have 2 values for the key group_"? It's not entirely clear what you mean by that. do you want to have distinct rows across `id1`, `id2`, `id3`? If so, how is the `value` column determined to have `tom` for the first 3 lines of your example?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care which one is chosen when there are duplicates (e.g between Tom and Tim), then do `ds.dropDuplicates("id1", "id2", "id3")`

If you care, you'll need to provide a way how to prioritize them.

Comment: no it will not work, in this case I should drop both Tom and Tim in fact